# Jenkins to run Maven build on Linux or Windows

Tags: linux, windows, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Maven build of a Java application that runs successfully on either Linux or Windows by typing the identical command `mvn install`.

However, using the [Jenkinsfile method](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) of setting up this build, on Linux that file needs to contain `sh mvn install` and on windows `bat mvn install`.

If paths and tools are configured appropriately on Windows, log shows:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[C:\tools\jenkins\workspace\DSL\master] Running shell script
sh: C:\tools\jenkins\workspace\DSL\master@tmp\durable-60527040\script.sh: command not found
```

Is there any way for a single Jenkinsfile to allow building in both environments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipeline scripts can contain groovy code, so branching with `if` is allowed. You can test your environment with `System.properties['os.name']` and depending on the result, use `sh` or `bat`:

```
node {
    def os = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase()
    echo "OS: ${os}"
    if (os.contains("linux")) {
      sh "mvn install" 
    } else {
      bat "mvn install"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your os detection method doesn't work for me.  For me os.name is always linux regardless of node.  However,    def isLinux() {        return null == env.windir}  does work.  Very unexpected