# Jenkinsfile 2 erros

Tags: jenkins, syntax-error

this is my simple jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages  {
        stages ('Build') {
            steps {

                sh 'echo "Hello World" '
                sh '''
                 echo "Multiline shell steps works too"
                 ls -lah
               '''
           }
        }        
     }
 }
```

But when i was executing this in jenkins i'm getting the below errors:

Branch indexing

Connecting to https://api.github.com using admin/****** (GitHub Access Token)

Obtained Jenkinsfile from 030d6e5dc55356678255ca506b05e8cc223d15a6

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

WorkflowScript: 4: Expected a stage @ line 4, column 9.

```
       stages ('Build') {

       ^
```

WorkflowScript: 3: No stages specified @ line 3, column 5.

```
   stages  {

   ^
```

2 errors

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)

at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)

at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)

at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)

at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Any idea what i am missing here. Thanks

Comment: may be you can check which os is jenkins try to builds - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252654/jenkins-to-run-maven-build-on-linux-or-windows

Comment: extra 's' in line     stages ('Build')    . It should be just      stage ('Build'). Visual Studio Code has a plugin for jenkisfile . It's not perfect but it saved me from lots of typos and missing brackets .

Comment: Thanks to @ – Iftimie Tu. It is working right now. Yes, I am going to add a plugin for jenkinsfile.